# Check If Simple Input is Valid

Tags: angularjs

I want to disable a button if a field is invalid. My only issue is that the field in the form is from a ng-repeat.

```
<button ng-disabled="!documentForm.askedTime.$valid">SAVE</button>
<form name"documentForm>
<div ng-repeat="document in vm.documents">
   <input name="askedTime //some regex here />
</div>
</form>
```

Basically I only want to enable the save button if there are no errors in the askedTime

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I only want to enable the save button if there are no errors in the askedTime

```
<form name"documentForm">
    <button ng-disabled="documentForm.$error"
            ng-click="save()">
        SAVE
    </button>  
    <div ng-repeat="document in vm.documents">
        <input name="askedTime_{{$index}}"
               ng-model="document.askedTime"
               required
        />
    </div>   
</form>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Reference - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)
- [AngularJS ngFormController API Reference - $error](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$error)